Does WhatsApp Business API support sending messages to WhatsApp groups?
I'm currently exploring the capabilities of the WhatsApp Business API for a project I'm working on. I'm wondering if the WhatsApp Business API supports sending messages to WhatsApp groups. I've read through the documentation, but I couldn't find a clear answer on this specific feature.
Could someone who has experience with the WhatsApp Business API clarify whether it supports sending messages to WhatsApp groups? If it does, are there any specific limitations or requirements that I should be aware of?
POST = https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{Phone-Number-ID}}/messages


Body = {
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to": "{{Recipient-Phone-Number}}",
    "type": "document",
    "document": {
        "link": "https://test.pdf",
        "filename": "Test"
    }
}


I found this github repo, implying it is not natively supported.
With Twilio's Conversations API, you can implement group chats in WhatsApp, a feature which is not offered natively in WhatsApp's API. With this code sample, you can implement multi-participant chat for up to 50 people that users can opt into and communicate through a single Twilio WhatsApp sender (business profile).
https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/whatsapp-group-messaging

WhatsApp Business API doesn't support sending messages to group but very soon WhatsApp is bringing this for WhatsApp Business API users.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
